# Groovy script not working in jenkins active choice reactive parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins 2.33 running on ubuntu 18.04, the groovy script which executes a shell script located at usr/local/bin and lists the branches of gitlab repo. groovy script collects each line as tags in active choice reactive parameter. But now with ubuntu 22.04 and java 11 , jenkins 2.36 its not working anymore. branches.sh located at usr/local/bin.I want the list generated by shell script to be appended into a list so that branch can be selected to build..
script is as below.

```
tags = []
text = "branches.sh https://gitlab.com/xyz/${services}.git".execute().text
text.eachLine { tags.push(it) }
return tags
```

Comment: I resolved it, Actually the issue was the plugin..

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Did you use a different plugin? Reinstall it? Upgrade it?

Comment: @varontron It was due to loading error somehow the plugin was not loaded